# remove white spaces between borders in table

Tags: html, css

I have some spaces between my borders in a table.
And I cant figure out why,
 been trying with negative margin so they overlap each other but the margin doesn't work.
since it's a table I have a left border on both `td` and `th`.
but I also have a space between the side borders and top/bottom border.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/pHVhg/1/) is the fiddle I created.

some table css

```
.profile-table {
  height: 100%;
}

.profile-table td { 
  text-align:   center;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size:    1.2em;
}

.profile-table th { 
  text-align:   center;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:        100px;
}

.profile-table tr{ 
}

.profile-table *:last-child{
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a CSS Reset like this [http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) ? I always use it in my pages, so I don't have problems with paddings, image borders and other strange things that some browsers (especially IE) do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `border-collapse:collapse` to merge borders

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pHVhg/2/)

Comment: Thanks. Had actually never heard of border:collapse before!
Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

add `border-collapse: collapse;` to your table (see [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-collapse))

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sWC9t/

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
<table class="profile-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
</table>
```

**Demo Here**

http://jsfiddle.net/pHVhg/3/

Comment: cellpadding and cellspacing are deprecated (since 1999)